# Using the correct Jquery selectors to migrate content between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

Majorly stuck here and would love some help. I am trying migrate the hidden div content of a particular topic to a separate area when it's specific title is clicked. At the minute I can get the content to migrate but instead of the specific topic content it just cycles through the content upon clicking.

Sorry for my poor Title, I'm struggling to define my exact problem. Please change if you feel you can do better.

http://jsfiddle.net/vBCs5/1/

Clicking the grey subtitles migrates the content.

Thank you in advance.

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".freemarker-wrap div").hide();

   $(".test").click(function () {

      $(".freemarker").each(function () {

        var working = $(this).contents();
        var ref = $(".content-box").contents();

        $(this).append(ref);
        $(".content-box").append(working);

   });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="page-wrap">
<div class="left-column-wrap">

<h1>FreeMarker +</h1>
<div class="freemarker-wrap">
    <span class="test">
        <h2>Lucene Call ></h2>
        <div class="freemarker">
        <p>Click to hide stories</p>
    </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
    <h2>Arrays ></h2>
    <div class="freemarker">
        <p>Arrays</p> 
    </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
<h2>Declaring and outputting variables ></h2>
    <div class="freemarker">
        <p>Declaring</p> 
    </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
    <h2>IF Statements ></h2>
    <div class="freemarker">
        <p>Statements</p>  
    </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
    <h2>Fragments ></h2>
    <div class="freemarker">
        <p>Fragments</p>
    </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
    <h2>Working with Numbers ></h2>
    <div class="freemarker">
        <h3>Numbers</h3>        
    </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
     <h2>Current Date ></h2>
     <div class="freemarker">     
        <p>Current</p>
     </div>
     </span>
 </div>

 <div class="javascript-wrap">
<h1>JavaScript +</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="javascript-wrap">
<h1>JQuery +</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="javascript-wrap">
<h1>HTML +</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="javascript-wrap">
<h1>CSS +</h1>
 </div>

 </div>

 <div class="content-box">
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @YogeshWaran I like this way using the contents() function but when the topic returns to the menu the content is no longer hidden. Is it possible to write the jquery so that it is hidden again after leaving the "content-box"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming this is what your are asking for...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".freemarker-wrap div").hide();
  $(".test").click(function () {
    var working=$(this).find(".freemarker").html(); // get that particular <span> html
    $(".content-box").html(working); <migrate it to content
 });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/gHSXb/1/) here

Comment: nice, just beat me to it ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over complicating it ;)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".freemarker-wrap div").hide();

  $("span.test").click(function () {
      $(".content-box").html( $(this).find("div.freemarker").html() );
    });

 });
```